# Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map, where $V$ is an inner product space. Given $T^2=\frac{T+T^*}{2}$, prove that $T$ is normal and that $T=T^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, idempotents, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space.

Given $T^2=\frac{T+T^{*}}{2}$, I would like to prove that $T$ is normal and that $T=T^2$.

The first part, to prove that $T$ is normal, is quite easy:
from $T^2=\frac{T+T^{*}}{2}$ we'll have $\,T^{*}=2T^2 - T$, and
as $TT^{*} = 2T^3 -T^2 = T^{*}T$.

Now, I need to prove that $T=T^*$, then $T = T^2$ is immediate.
I have been thinking about this question for some days and I can't figure out in what technique to prove that $T = T^{*}$.

Comment: Could you please give a source for this question?

Comment: @Hanno a question from a past final exam in the class linear algebra 2 in the open university of israel. i translated the question for the matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ must satisfy $\lambda^2 = \frac{\lambda + \bar \lambda}{2}$. For $\lambda = a + bi$ ($a,b$ real), this means that
$$
(a + bi)^2 = a \implies 
\begin{cases} 
a^2 - a - b^2 = 0\\
2 ab = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Consider the cases of $a = 0,b = 0$ separately.

Answer (score 2):

We have $T^2 = \frac{T + T^*}{2}$. Therfore, $(T^2)^* = \frac{T^* + (T^*)^*}{2} = \frac{T + T^*}{2} = T^2$. Combining, $(T^2)^* = T^2$. Therefore $T^2$ is Hermitian. Diagonalize $T^2$ to write $T^2 = V D V^{-1}$, which indicates $T = V D^{\frac{1}{2}} V^{-1}$. It indicates $T$ is also Hermitian.

Comment: I suppose I haven't studied yet the theorem that allows you to perform the transition between $(1)\ \ T^2 = VDV^{-1}$ to $(2) \ \ T=VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^{-1}$. could you refer me to the theorem that proves that?

Comment: Find here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_diagonalization

Comment: The diagonal matrix $D$ may have negative entries. For instance, let
$T=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. We have $T^*=-T$, hence $T$ is normal, but not Hermitian. Its square $T^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -1&0\\ 0&-1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is Hermitian. $\qquad$
This cannot happen if $T$ is already Hermitian -- and this in turn is the target, not the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

for a slightly different approach, write
$T^2=\frac{1}{2} \big(T+T^*\big) = (T^*)^2$
$T=\frac{1}{2}\big(T+T^*\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(T-T^*\big)$
and estimate the skew hermitian part by considering
$\dim \ker\Big(\big(T-T^*\big)\Big) = \dim \ker\Big(T\big(T-T^*\big)T^*\Big)$
(due to normality of $T$)

$T\big(T-T^*\big)T^*$
$=T^2 T^* - T(T^*)^2$
$= \frac{1}{2}\Big(\big(T+T^*\big)T^* - T\big(T+T^*\big)\Big)$
$= \frac{1}{2}\Big(TT^*+(T^*)^2 - T^2-TT^*\Big)$
$=\mathbf 0$
$\longrightarrow \big(T-T^*\big) = \mathbf 0$
$\longrightarrow T=\frac{1}{2}\big(T+T^*\big) = T^2$

Answer (score 1):

The following also works in an infinite-dimensional inner product space.

The initial condition $\,T^2=\frac12 (T^*+T)\,$ shows that $\,T^2$ is self-adjoint. Writing it equivalently as
$$T^2-T \;=\; \frac{T^* -T}{2}\tag{1}$$
we get that $\,T$ is idempotent iff $\,T$ is self-adjoint.
Multiply the condition in its initial form with $(1)$ to obtain
$$T^3\big(T-\mathbb 1\big) \;=\;T^2\big(T^2-T\big) \;=\;
\frac14\big((T^*)^2 -T^2 -T^*T +TT^*\big) \;=\; 0\,,$$
the vanishing is due to the self-adjointness of $T^2$ and $T$ being normal.
Normal operators have the feature that their kernel does not grow upon
iteration(${}^1$), i.e., $\ker T^r=\ker T\,$ for all $r=2,3,\dots\,$
Hence $\,\operatorname{im}(T-\mathbb 1)\subset\ker T^3=\ker T$,
and $\,T\,(T-\mathbb 1)=0\,$ follows.

---

$\quad 1\;$ See for instance Lemma $1$ in [this lecture](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Emikehill/Teaching/Math5651/Lecture28.pdf#page=3) .